# DocumentRoot is password protected but no htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-12.04, password-protection, .htpasswd

At some point I pw protected `/var/www/` for security purposes (my actual hosted websites are located in a different path), now I would like to host something publicly in `/var/www/` but do not know how to remove the pw protection. There is no `.htaccess` file present in the directory or the parent.

What other ways could the directory be protected? Some sort of apache config file?

Comment: Yes, `.htaccess` is really just a per-directory extension of the global Apache `httpd.conf` config file.

Comment: This question is more about ubuntu configuration. If you password-protected a folder, none of its child folders will be accessible without the pw. I suggest you ask your question here : http://askubuntu.com/